# The average of the items of $(0,10]$

Tags: means

The question says it. Let $A = \{\,x \,|\, 0 < x \le 10\,\}$. What would be the average of all the items in this set? How do you prove it?
**UPDATE**
$x$ belongs to the set of real numbers.My thoughts:Is it possible to find the average of the items of $A = {x|0 <= x <= 10}$ where $x$ belongs to the set of real numbers?If it is, why couldn’t we use the same approach for my question?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: To what set do the $x$'s belong? If it's $\mathbb N$, then you will be able to add and average the items. But if it's $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb R$, you will have to change your question since these the interval for these 2 sets has an infinite number of elements.

Comment: $x$ belongs to the set of real numbers

Comment: For a closed interval we have the average value function from calculus. But for open/non closed intervals this is interesting

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What kind of class do you need it for? Calculus? Probability theory?

Comment: It’s for probability theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering $(0,10]$ or $[0,10]$ as subspaces of $\mathbb R$ with the Lebesgue measure $\mu$, the question of "average" is a measure theoretic (or probability theoretic) one. While average of a finite set $X\subset\mathbb R$ may be defined as
$$
\frac{1}{|X|} \sum_{x\in X} x,
$$
we can define the average of a set $X\subset\mathbb R$ of finite measure $\mu(X)<\infty$ as the Lebesgue integral
$$
\frac{1}{\mu(X)} \int_X x\,\mathrm d\mu(x).
$$
When $X=(0,10]$ or $X=[0,10]$ you have $\mu(X)=10$ and obtain the average
$$
\frac{1}{10} \int_0^{10} x\,\mathrm dx =5.
$$